# How to sum the rows in group by - oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table:

```
 Name         Amount       DB         CR

 Person A     1000         0           0
 Person A     5000         100        300
 Person A     3000         200         0
 Person A     0            100         300
 Person B     1000         0           0
 Person B     5000         0           0
 Person B     3000         0           0
 Person B     0            1000        2000
 Person C     10000        0           0
 Person C     50000        0           0
```

I need to display the total amount after Credit and Debit.

```
Person=sum(Amount)-(sum(DB)+sum(CR)).
```

How to write a query to display the output in Oracle?

Comment: what have you have tried so far?

Comment: Are you sure you have got the formula right?

Comment: What do you intend to calculate?

Answer (score 0):

With the formula you proposed:

```
select name, sum(Amount)-(sum(DB)+sum(CR)) 
  from your_table
group by name;
```

...